# IndexedDB Database not persisting in chrome app

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, indexeddb, google-chrome-app

I created a database in my app's background script on install:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(
    function(details)
    {
        if ( details.reason === "install" )
        {
            ...elided opening database...
            request.onupgradeneeded: function(event)
            {
                console.log( "Upgrading" );             
                var database =  event.target.result;
                var transaction = database.transaction;

                transaction.onerror = function(event) { console.log( "trans error" ); };
                transaction.oncomplete = function(event) { console.log( "trans complete" ); };
                transaction.onabort = function(event) { console.log( "trans aborted" ); };

                var store = database.createObjectStore( "mystore", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true } );
                console.log( "created store" );
            }
        }
    }
);
```

This worked perfectly. I then put data into the store and read it out again. I then changed some other code in my app and updated again (about 4-5 times) but never changing the database code or structure. No other method called used "onupgradeneeded".

After shutting down the computer and starting it up again later, this time I'm getting an error when I try to read from the database that says the object store doesn't exist and that the database has no object stores!

This is not the first time this has happened. Does this happen to anyone else? What can be done to make it persist across updates and restarts?

**EDIT** Updated code to remove my custom classes

Comment: IDBEvent is deprecated and unnecessary, why are you using it?

Comment: @JoshFroelich Sorry, IDBEvent is a class I made myself to deal with events easier. It's not the deprecated one. So, instead of having to do `var db = event.target.result;` you can do: `var db = idbEvent.database;`

Comment: You should consider choosing responses to your other questions as answers if you want people to continue to help you.

Comment: so does this happen without closing the browser?

it may be because you are clearing the browser cache including offline website data manually or the brwoser settings are set to delete website data and history on close